# Enhancing the performance of custom spaCy NER models when applied to extensive data sourced from Excel columns

Tags: python, nlp, named-entity-recognition, spacy-3, named-entity-extraction

Utilizing custom spaCy NER models stored in a designated directory, how can we expedite the entity extraction process for substantial data across multiple Excel columns in Python?

Looped through each cell using all available NER models to retrieve the entity type for each cell, and stored the results in separate columns. While entity extraction worked efficiently on small datasets, it faced significant delays when processing larger volumes of data.